# how to pass dynamic query params in url from array object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular8

I am getting array object like this:
[image]

i am showing one third party form using `<iframe>` in angular. Now i want to pass query params in url so that that form should b pre-filled. 
My form can be pre filled if i enter this url :

```
http://myform.com?d[/data/patch_form/crop1]=abc&d[/data/patch_form/name]=xyz (this is hard coded)
```

in which after `"/patch_form/"` is a key which is also present in my object.

how can i pass this array object's all keys and value in my url so that all keys can be pass through url.?

> .html

```
 <iframe id="iframe" [src]="pathFormUrl | safe" height="400px" width="100%"
            frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

> .ts console line

```
console.log(this.selectedTimeLine.formKeyValues)
```

Answer (score 0):

what did you try?
A quick look at the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) gives this example.

```
    // Set our navigation extras object
    // that contains our global query params and fragment
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { 'session_id': sessionId },
    };

    // Redirect to the login page with extras
    return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login'], navigationExtras);
```